# How to change button CSS attributes

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a submit button that has an image located on the bottom of a form.  That image is on other parts of the page that need to be there, however the button doesn't need it and instead needs to be changed into a plain black button.  I suspect there is a child/parent issue that is preventing me from doing what I need.  I tried moving certain styles up and down on the .css file to try to override the hierarchy, but nothing works.  I am new to the whole Web Development game and would like an easy to follow explanation on how to do this.  Thank you.

EDIT:  There might be some code that is elsewhere in the CSS file that is overriding what I have shown here.  I will put a URL instead of putting the 300 lines of code to see if that will help you guys help me.  Again, thank you for helping a Web noob.

URL:  https://crux.baker.edu/~jbachm01/CHAMPS/SideKick%20Main%20Files/sidekick/

HTML

```html
<div class="grid_4">
      <div id="signup-form" class="clearfix">
        <h2>Sign Up With US...its free!</h2>
        <form action="">
          <p>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input name="" type="text" />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input name="" type="text" />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input name="" type="text" />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Additional Information</label>
            <input name="" type="text" />
          </p>
          <p class="last">
            <button type="submit" class="button"><span>SUBMIT</span></button>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```css
#signup-form {
padding: 15px;

/* 
width: 200px;
height: 400px;
FIX FORM SIZE HERE!!!
*/

}
#signup-form h2 {
text-align: center;
font-size:24px;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform:uppercase;
width:100%;
padding: 0 15px;
margin: 0 -15px 25px;
background: url(../images/line.png) repeat-x left bottom;
padding-bottom:10px;
}
#signup-form label {
font-size:16px;
display: block;
margin-bottom:10px;
line-height:1;
}
#signup-form input[type=text], #signup-form textarea {
background-color:#fff;
border: none;
border-top: solid 3px #bababa;
width:250px;
padding: 9px 10px;font-size:14px;
}
#signup-form p.last {
margin-bottom: 0;
}
#signup-form button, #signup-form button > span {
display: block;
width:100%;
border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
}
#signup-form button > span {
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
font-size:16px;
text-align:center;
line-height: 68px;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ynYy7/

Comment: Seems fine to me... What is the problem?

Comment: Why do you need two span's?

Comment: Why do you need any span?

Comment: If I remove the double <span> the button goes away and only the "submit" text remains.  I was able to remove the double and leave it a single, but it (the single span) needs to be there for the button to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following code near the top of the CSS file...

```
#signup-form, .link-more {
background: url(../images/form_background.jpg);
}
```

It now looks exactly how I need it to look.

Answer (score 0):

In `#signup-form button` add:

```
padding: 0;
border: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the `<span>` tags for in the button? Your code:

```html
<button type="submit" class="button"><span><span>SUBMIT</span></span></button>
```

This could simply be:

```html
<button type="submit" class="button">SUBMIT</button>
```

As for making the button black (or rather, the half-opaque black that you have currently), your CSS could be something like:

```css
#signup-form button {
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
display: block;
width: 100%;
font-size:16px;
text-align:center;
line-height: 68px;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/T7j7P/

Comment: I was able to remove one of the spans, but getting rid of them both will change the button in a way that is further from what I want.  I edited the original post to see if I could clear things up a little.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

looks fine indeed. I would suggest some changes to your markup:

- remove the `p` tags, and replace by a semantically more correct `ul`
- remove the double `span` inside your `button`, and try to achive the effect with `box-shadow`

This is what my code would look like: http://jsfiddle.net/nfdvm/

note that the css3 code still needs prefixing, should work fine in Chrome though

Can you indicate what you would like to see different, cause your question is not very clear to me...

Comment: If I replace the p tags with ul the spacing of the form elements moves out of whack...and the image I have in the background of the form does not display as needed.  What I basically need is to have plain colored button instead of the button with image as I have now.  I will edit my original post to see if I can clear things up.  I'm a Web Industry noob, so please excuse my slight ignorance on some things.